# No web3 instance injected following the dApp University Tutorials

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask, react

I've been following Dapp University's videos on how to make IPFS uploads with Euthereum Smart contracts, and after I manage to 'npm run start' in the command line it opens up the HTML, but it always gives me this error: 'No web3 instance injected, using local web3.'

[image]

Here is the link to the first video: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SkMH0WeRYtg&t=1s

And here is the link to his code: 
https://github.com/dappuniversity/ipfs_image_uploader

I have a suspicion that the issue might lie within the getWeb3.js file, but maybe you had the same issue and know how to complete the tutorial, in any case, I would really appreciate your help!

This is the code of the getWeb3.js file :

import Web3 from 'web3'

let getWeb3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  // Wait for loading completion to avoid race conditions with web3 injection timing.
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var results
    var web3 = window.web3

```
// Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
if (typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined') {
  // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider.
  web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider)

  results = {
    web3: web3
  }

  console.log('Injected web3 detected.');

  resolve(results)
} else {
  // Fallback to localhost if no web3 injection. We've configured this to
  // use the development console's port by default.
  var provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:9545')

  web3 = new Web3(provider)

  results = {
    web3: web3
  }

  console.log('No web3 instance injected, using Local web3.');

  resolve(results)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)

You need to install the MetaMask extension

Comment: I have the metamask extension for google chrome

Comment: Then you will need to enable it (turn privacy off), because MetaMask is in privacy mode by default